# insert data into tables where ids need to be equal

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have two tables, customer and order each with two records for 2020. The ******* starred values are what I want to add for FY 2021.

Customer:

| ID | FY | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020 | Tina Smith |
| 2 | 2020 | Bobby Brown |
| 134 | 2021 | Tina Smith*** |
| 234 | 2021 | Bobby Brown*** |

Order

| ID | 2digitFY | Food | Drink |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20 | Hot Dog | Water |
| 2 | 20 | Burger | Soda |
| 134 | 21 | Hot Dog | Water*** |
| 234 | 21 | Burger | Soda *** |

I want to add records to  both tables that is the same data for FY 2020/20 just new sequence numbers with the year 2021/21**starred data above**. I can't figure out how I would make the new ids equal when they auto generate. Below is similar code I have set up (fake data used above).

```
insert into customer (id, fy, name)
    select (id, '2021', name)
    from customer
    where fy = '2020'

insert into order (id, 2digitFY, food, drink)
    select (id, '21', food, drink)
    from order
    where 2digitFY = '20'
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can't figure out how I would make the new ids equal when they auto generate.

If what you said means those columns are primary keys which are automatically generated, then you don't have control over it, Oracle does.

I presume that "auto generate" you said means *identity column* whose value is automatically generated. If so, modify it so that it uses `GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL` option. It means that - if you don't provide `ID` value, Oracle will generate it. But, if you provide it, its value will be the one you inserted.

Similarly, if you're on 11g or lower (where identity columns didn't exist) and created those values by database triggers, make sure that they fire and populate `ID` columns only when their values are `NULL`.

If you do that, then you'll be able to create your own ID values and insert them as you wish.

Comment: i believe we generate it by default on null. as in  when a record is added, the db assigns it whatever value is next that hasnt been used. My issue that is I cant figure out how to make it so when i insert the tables, i want some way to verify the record stil match between the tables and have new but same ids in the table when inserted. Im afraid oracle will just assign them values that will not match and then we wont be able to find out what ties to what.

Comment: As I said: if you provide ID values, Oracle won't generate them. So - calculate those IDs and insert rows using those values.